# MongoDB can't get collection in another file in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

This is my account.js file

```
accounts.mongoConnect = function (){
    MongoClient.connect(MongoConfig.uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, (error, client) => {
        if (error) {
            throw error;
        }
        database = client.db(MongoConfig.dbName);
        collection = database.collection(MongoConfig.collections[0]);
        console.log("Connected to `" + MongoConfig.dbName + "`!");
        //console.log(collection)
    });
}
```

and this is my companies.js file

```
companies.mongoConnect = function (){
    MongoClient.connect(MongoConfig.uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, (error, client) => {
        if (error) {
            throw error;
        }
        database = client.db(MongoConfig.dbName);
        console.log(MongoConfig.collections);
        collection = database.collection(MongoConfig.collections[1]);
        console.log("Companies.js Connected to `" + MongoConfig.dbName + "`!");
    });
}
```

When i run my app.js there is console log from account.js only, there is no console.log from companies.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing problem with your code. I have checked it look pretty fine from my side.
Have you done setting up the connection?

Should be like this, connected mongodb to your app node js.

```
httpsServer.listen(serverConfig.port, () => {
    accounts.mongoConnect(); 
    companies.mongoConnect(); 
});
```

Comment: Yeah i just miss this call this function httpsServer.listen. Thanks a lot mate